# MULE-4: Logging SFTP login attempts

Tags: connection, sftp, mule4, login-attempts

We need to log each time sftp connector make a attempt to login into SFTP server.
We are listening on SFTP server using new or update sftp component and wants to log each time connector makes an attempt to login into SFTP server.
EDIT##
Is there a way to override the methods implemented for SFTP connection internally to achieve this request.
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-sftp-connector

Answer (score 0):

The SFTP connector doesn't notify the login attempts. If it can connect, log in, and detects new files, then it will trigger the flow execution. But I don't think that there is a login event that can be tracked.

Comment: Is there a way to override the methods implemented internally to achieve this request?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The connector just doesn't keep track of logins. Are you interested on login attempts or general failures?
The connector itself is open source. You could try to add the feature yourself, but then you will have to maintain it.

Comment: I just need to log the login attempts to debug how many login attempts were made in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

We can track login attempts by enabling debug logs as per this documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/enable-verbose-logging